# Detect current device channel from code behind

Tags: device-channel

[From MSDN article about device channels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj862343.aspx):

> Also, device channels can set a JavaScript variable called `effectiveDeviceChannel` that contains the current channel alias. This variable can be used to show which channel is currently being used.

Is there similar variable, that could be used in code behind (in C#), to determine which channel is currently used?

Comment: What is the objective? Using a DeviceChannelPanel I think is the way to go in most cases (setting the IncludedChannels property to show or hide based on which channel the user is entering from) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.devicechannelpanel.includedchannels.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var effectiveMobileChannel = HttpContext.Current.Items["EffectiveMobileChannel"];
```

Source: from [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9167dcfe-799c-42da-a7f4-752269dba3a3/detect-current-device-channel-from-code-behind?forum=sharepointdevelopment)